# enum in zod validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, zod

I have a schema in zod and have an object.

```
const escortTypeOptions = [
    { value: "Nutrition", label: "תזונה" },
    { value: "Training", label: "אימונים" },
    { value: "Nutrition and Training", label: "תזונה ואימונים" },
];

const escortTypeValues = escortTypeOptions.map((option) => option.value);
```

for instance this is the z.object:

```
z.object({
...some fields,
escortType: z.enum([...escortTypeValues]), {
            errorMap: (issue, ctx) => ({ message: 'Please choose on of the options' })
        }),
});
```

but getting Typescript error

```
    No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(values: readonly [string, ...string[]], params?: RawCreateParams): ZodEnum<[string, ...string[]]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly [string, ...string[]]'.
      Source provides no match for required element at position 0 in target.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(values: [string, ...string[]], params?: RawCreateParams): ZodEnum<[string, ...string[]]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string, ...string[]]'.
      Source provides no match for required element at position 0 in target.
```

when typing "as const"

```
    const escortTypeValues = escortTypeOptions.map((option) => option.value) as const;
```

getting another error

```
A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.
```

Answer (score 0):

`z.enum` requires the type `[string, ...string[]]`, which practically means an array of strings with a length of at least one.

Given that you are converting constants in code, I recommend using a simple cast:

```
const escortTypeValues = escortTypeOptions.map((option) => option.value) as [string, ...string[]];
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the types intact? I have a similar issue and would like to keep the type as ```["Nutrition", Training","Nutrition and Training"]``` instead of casting it to ```[string, ...string[]]```